# Keras - Wrong input shape in LSTM dense layer

Tags: python, keras, lstm, text-classification

I am trying to build an `lstm` text classifier using `Keras`.

This is the model structure:

```
model_word2vec = Sequential()
model_word2vec.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_dimension,
                    output_dim=embedding_dim,
                    weights=[word2vec_weights,
                    input_length=longest_sentence,
                    mask_zero=True,
                    trainable=False))
model_word2vec.add(LSTM(units=embedding_dim, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, return_sequences=True))
model_word2vec.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model_word2vec.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


results = model_word2vec.fit(X_tr_word2vec, y_tr_word2vec, validation_split=0.16, epochs=3, batch_size=128, verbose=0)
```

Where `y_tr_word2vec` is a 3-dimensional `one-hot` encoded variable.

When I run the code above, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (15663, 3)
```

I suppose that the issue could be about `y_tr_word2vec` shape or the `batch size` dimension, but I'm not sure.

**Update:**

I have changed `return_sequences=False`, `y_tr_word2vec` from `one-hot` to `categorical`, `1` neuron in dense layer, and now I am using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `categorical_crossentropy`.

Now, I get this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'countess'`.

Therefore now I suppose that, during `fit()`, something goes wrong with the input vector `X_tr_word2vec`, which contains the sentences.

Comment: did you try **keras.utils.to_categorical(y_tr_word2vec, num_classes=3)** ? It seems your input to the model is not correct.

Comment: The number of neurons in your models are assigned by variables which we cannot see, please post them. I mean `vocabulary_dimension`,
`embedding_dim`, and if there are any others. Also `dim_embedding` and `embedding_dim` are two different things, is this intended?

Comment: @DanielR. These are the same variable, I have updated the test.

Comment: @AmirHadifar I have tried, as I have wrote in the updates. Now, I get this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'countess'`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this code

```
model_word2vec.add(LSTM(units=dim_embedding, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, return_sequences=True))
model_word2vec.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

You have set `return_sequences=True` ,which means LSTM will return a 3D array to dense layer,,whereas dense does not need 3D data...so delete return_sequences=True

```
model_word2vec.add(LSTM(units=dim_embedding, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25))
model_word2vec.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

why did u set return_sequences=True?

Comment: I have tried, but now I get `'[12406  9070  6608  9899  7373  5589 ......] are not in index`.